# How to compute the (C/D)th root of (A/B) with arbitrary precision for arbitrarily large integers A, B, C and D?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, numbers

I want to compute some (C/D)th root of (A/B) with **arbitrary precision** for the decimal expansion of the root (for example, if the desired precision is an integer `E`, the result should contain `E` digits **after the decimal point** of the root; `E` may be equal to at least tens of thousands; A, B, C, D are integers containing tens of thousands decimal digits), but all Javascript math libraries that I have found will refuse to deal with such numbers.
I tried to use [Decimal.js](http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/), but it has a limited precision and limited size of the input. For example, if I want to compute the square root of 2 with 1025 significant digits (where the last digit may be rounded somehow), I used the following code for Decimal.js:

```
Decimal.set({ precision: 1025 });
var r2 = Decimal.pow(2, Decimal.div(1, 2)).toDP(1025).toString();
console.log(r2);
```

but I get

```
Error: [DecimalError] Precision limit exceeded
```

Is it possible to solve the problem using client-side (working in the browser) Javascript? As far as I know, there are some efficient algorithms to compute the roots even for **millions** of digits, but I didn't see any of these implemented in JS for arbitrarily large numbers and arbitrary precision. Is it possible at all?

Comment: `Precision: 1025` :-o

Comment: You might want to set the internal working precision higher than the displayed precision, 1 digit every 2 or 3 operations in a computation chain plus a buffer of say 3. This would give here `Decimal.set({ precision: 1029 });`

Comment: @LutzL: I don't understand... what code should I use to get, say, 1500 digits of square root of two in Decimal.js? Moreover, as far as I understand, Decimal.js cannot deal with integers greater than 2^1024.

Comment: I do not know what page opens for you, on my version it says "**precision** number: integer, 1 to 1e+9 inclusive, Default value: 20". Where do you get 2^1024?

Answer (score 0):

in `decimal.js`, Setting `precision` to `1025` gives you a total of 1025 (mantissa) decimal digits in a number.

`.toDP(1025)` refers to digits after the decimal points, or decimal places, which requires in this example a total of 1026 mantissa digits, as there is one digit `1` before the decimal point.

It can be assumed that the methods use an appropriately increased internal working precision, so that the output is correct relative to rounding. Which means that the last digit may not be the same if recomputed in higher precision. Set the rounding mode to `round-down` (towards zero) if you want to prevent that.

---

The reason that the power method fails with precision greater than 1020 is that the internal precision exceeds 1025 which is the length of the internal `LN10` constant given as a string. The error is because of the explicit test against this situation.

You might for this library use a 1000 digit result as initial point for the Newton method to get improved results.

```js
my_div = document.getElementById("my_div")
Decimal.set({precision:1010});
var a = Decimal.pow(new Decimal(2), Decimal.div(1,2))
my_div.innerHTML += "initial pr=1000 : "+a.toDP(1000);
Decimal.set({precision:2500});
for(var k=1; k<=4; k++) {
  a = Decimal.div(a.add(Decimal.div(2,a)),2);
  my_div.innerHTML += "<br> Newton "+k+" : "+a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/master/decimal.js"></script>
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

Comment: And how can I use Decimal.js to see the first 1500 decimal digits after the decimal point of sqrt(2)? It does not matter what precision I choose, but I always get an error after around ~1000 digits. Moreover, how can I deal with numbers greater than 2^1024? For example, trying to use `new Decimal('0b1...')` with more than 1024 binary digits will produce an error.

Comment: You can not use the power function (and probably also exp and log) with a precision larger than about 1020, because their code contains the `LN10` constant that is "only" provided with 1025 digits. You can use Newton to refine polynomial roots, see the last edit and example.

Comment: As far as I understand, this method relies on knowing derivatives of powers. I don't think it can be applied to big numbers using decimal.js.

Comment: You have to solve `f(X)=X^D-A`. Its derivative is `f'(X)=A*X^(D-1)`. The Newton step as always `X=X-f(X)/f'(X)`. You would need to implement your own `powint` procedure for (positive) integer exponents that does not rely on the provided `pow` function because of its precision limitations. Example codes for the halving-and-squaring algorithm are easy to find. -- Alternatives are the third order Halley method or the power/Taylor series for `(1+(A/X^D)-1)^(1/D)` or `(1+(X^D/A-1))^(-1/D)`.